# context.beginPath() is not a function - why?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build an analogue clock SP feature, but before anything else, I've put it in an HTML file to provide proof of concept.

In an HTML file, separate from SharePoint, the code runs perfectly fine, no problem (in IE, Chrome and Firefox).

However, if I point a Content Editor web part to this file, the canvas draws but the `setInterval` doesn't fire because I get this:

> Uncaught TypeError: `ctx.beginPath` is not a function

How do I resolve that?

#### Code (edited):

```html
<canvas id="abcdef" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

(function() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("abcdef");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var radius = canvas.height / 2;

    ctx.translate(radius, radius);
    radius = radius * 0.90;
    drawClock(ctx);
    setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

    function drawClock(context) {

        drawFace(context);
        drawNumbers(context);
        drawTime(context);
    }

    function drawFace(ctx) {

        var grad;

        console.info(ctx);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
        ctx.fill()

        grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, radius * 0.95, 0, 0, radius * 1.05);
        grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
        grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
        grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
        ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
        ctx.lineWidth = radius * 0.1;
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, radius * 0.1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fill();
    }

    function drawNumbers(ctx) {

        var ang;
        var num;
        ctx.font = radius * 0.15 + "px arial";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        for (num = 1; num < 13; num++) {
        ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
        ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, radius * 0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
    }
    }

    function drawTime(ctx) {

        var now = new Date();
        var hour = now.getHours();
        var minute = now.getMinutes();
        var second = now.getSeconds();

        //hour
        hour = hour % 12;
        hour = (hour * Math.PI / 6) + (minute * Math.PI / (6 * 60)) + (second * Math.PI / (360 * 60));
        drawHand(hour, radius * 0.5, radius * 0.07, "grey");

        //minute
        minute = (minute * Math.PI / 30) + (second * Math.PI / (30 * 60));
        drawHand(minute, radius * 0.8, radius * 0.07, "black");

        // second
        second = (second * Math.PI / 30);
        drawHand(second, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02, "red");
    }

    function drawHand(pos, length, width, colour) {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = width;
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.strokeStyle = colour;
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.rotate(pos);
        ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.rotate(-pos);
    }

}());

</script>
```

Comment: It is probally something to do with the scope,  try to declare the context in the `drawClock` function and pass it as a parameter, to see if it is a scope issue. Or just `console.info(ctx)` before the `beginPath` function call, to see if the object is set.

Comment: I've done what you said and now the error states: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'beginPath' of undefined" - also the console says "undefined" after doing console.info(ctx)

Comment: You've edited your code to include both my answer _and_ @winner_joiner's comment above.  If you roll it back to your _original_ code, and apply my answer only, does that help?

Comment: I hope your hints help solve the problem, i will stop updating my answer for now, not to create too much confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't explain, well try this:

```js
(function() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("abcdef");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var radius = canvas.height / 2;

    ctx.translate(radius, radius);
    radius = radius * 0.90;

    setInterval(function(){
      drawClock(ctx);
    }, 1000);

    function drawClock(context) {

        drawFace(context);
        drawNumbers(context);
        drawTime(context);
    }

  /* the rest */

 }());
```

because `setInterval(drawClock, 1000);` this line invoces the `drawClock` function every second with like this `drawClock()`.

But if you pass this function to the setInterval:

```
    setInterval(function(){
      drawClock(ctx);
    }, 1000);
```

the `drawClock` function will be called with the correct context, due to javascript closure "feature".

**Update:** this works on my system, but if your code of before stopped working on sharepoint, i can't guarantee it, nevertheless an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) should solve possible conflicts.

Comment: that's got it, thank you so much! sorry for being a pain, i'm pretty new to this..

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting suggests that the global variable, `ctx`, is being used elsewhere in the page you're embedded inside, and is being overridden after your code has executed.  The easiest solution to this, if your code otherwise works elsewhere, is to simply wrap it all in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), so all your variables are then locally scoped:

```
(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("abcdef");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var radius = canvas.height / 2;

    /* etc - include all your functions here too */
}());
```

This way none of your variables will conflict with any others that share the same name at the global scope.

Comment: I've edited my code in the question - unfortunately I'm still getting the same error as above (Cannot read property)

Comment: "cannot read property" is an entirely different error to "is not a function".  I note you state you got that error after trying something from the comments above - are you sure you've tried wrapping your code that works in a standalone page with a function as mentioned in my answer, rather than some modified code?

Comment: It's not a global conflict, it's just his `setInterval` doesn't pass `ctx` parameter to `drawClock`

Comment: @Matt Check the original post - he's updated it (badly) to include my answer and also a comment from under the Q.  Been tempted to roll it back, but was unsure whether I should.

Comment: @JamesThorpe his code still has `setInterval(drawClock, 1000);` which simply won't pass the necessary `ctx` parameter that `drawClock` expects

Comment: @Matt All the functions in the original code made use of the global `ctx` variable - there were no parameters being passed.  Just wrapping it in another function should have been all that was required - look at revision 3.  Rev 4 makes use of my answer + an attempt to incorporate the comment under the question, which broke it again.

Comment: @James it's a shame that much .. erm .."context" is lost in revisions. You might want to update your answer to reflect the current state of the question, as nobody goes revision digging. At this point `winner_joiner`'s answer makes more sense because it matches the question

Comment: @Matt I'm more tempted to rollback to rev3 since the OP has just confused himself more by trying two things at once.  Or just delete my answer - this particular Q&A has just got messy...